# Does AVPlayer support DVB Bitmap subtitles?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, media, avplayer, subtitle

I currently work at a cable TV provider in Brazil which requires DVB Bitmap for some of its assets. I've searched quite alot on Google and Stackoverflow and haven't found any denial or confirmation about this.

Does AVPlayer support DVB Bitmap subtitles? If not, which subtitle types does it support?

Comment: From my expirience it only works with WebVTT. But in iOS application we added supporting for SMPTE-tt and TTML. We parsed TTML subtitles and displayed on AVPlayerView. SMPTE-tt - image based subtitles, provided as base64 encoded data.

Comment: @IgorKotkovets would you care to tell me how did you do it? Did you open the manifest separately or did you subclass AVPlayer to implement it? Did it sync well?

Comment: we observed AVPlayerItem's `timedMetadata` property `[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata"           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew               context:TimedMetadataContext];`
Then in received callback we took `extraAttributes`. 
`for (AVMetadataItem *timedMetadata in playerItem.timedMetadata) {   
        NSDictionary *extras = timedMetadata.extraAttributes;
    }`
`extraAttributes ` contained subtitles. Just log this dictionary to see the  all data which it does contain

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @IgorKotkovets another quick question, how did you add these subtitles to the subtitle list from AVPlayer? Did you implement your own custom subtitle selection?

Comment: yes, we implemented custom subtitles selection