# How to render DVB Bitmap subtitles in iOS? Which API should be used?

Tags: ios, bitmap, subtitle, dvb

Following link provides how to get the list of DVB Bitmap subtitles. But after getting the list of subtitles how to render it on iOS device? which API call must be used?

[Does AVPlayer support DVB Bitmap subtitles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077711/does-avplayer-support-dvb-bitmap-subtitles)

Comment: Can any one help me how to display SMPTE-TT subtitles on iOS native player ?

Comment: @IgorKotkovets Can you help me how to render the SMPTE-TT subtitles on iOS?